# Safety of cookies in codeigniter (and in general)

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I do not fully understand the vulnerability of cookies, except that through reading it seems they can be changed...

Regardless, it seems like somewhat common practice to store user 'roles' or 'permissions' in a cookie.

Is it an incorrect assumption that this is the norm?

How else would one go about trying to secure a user role? 
Would I have to query the DB every time I wanted to get the user's role?

I am working with codeigniter right now and do stuff like

```
$this->session->set_userdata('role') = 'admin';
```

then access it like

```
if ($this->userdata('role') == 'admin'){
    allow access to important web aspects... and special database inserts
}
```

Sincere thanks for any help or further understanding.

Comment: Cookies are not for security. If you rely on a cookie for the security roles then the user can give themselves more access.

Comment: cookies should be relied on as much as something the user could enter into a textbox on every request. session tokens and other user-specified settings. never anything that you wouldn't want the user to fiddle with.

Comment: What if the cookies are encrypted (as they are in Codeigniter)?

Comment: Don't confuse cookies with sessions.... a session cookie on the web browser holds nothing but a session id; on the server, the session id points to a file that holds the session data that your PHP code is accessing.... the session data is __not__ accessible from the web browser

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using cookies to store permissions is that cookies are *client-side storage*, meaning that they are saved on the user's machine, and can therefore be modified by the user - that's a huge security flaw.

In that regard, storing permissions and any sensitive data in a cookie is far from being the norm - it's fundamentally flawed.

That being said however, there is a way to store such data in cookies in a secure way and the CodeIgniter (version 2.2+) Session library does it - it uses a Message Authentication Code (MAC) to verify that the cookie hasn't been modified.
If the verification fails, the cookie is discarded and that way you'd never allow a user-modified cookie to bypass any permissions that you've previously set in there.

The cookie encryption (which you mentioned in the comments) prevents the user (or any attacker) from reading the data, but doesn't provide any authenticity guarantees - the MAC does that.